# Catch all checked exceptions and turn into unchecked exception

Tags: java, error-handling, lambda

I am currently trying to learn Lambdas and following the book Java SE8 for the really Impatient and just finished Chapter 1 of it. This is the question, I am trying to get done with:

> Didn’t you always hate it that you had to deal with checked exceptions
>   in a Runnable? Write a method uncheck that catches all checked
>   exceptions and turns them into unchecked exceptions. For example,
>
> ```
> new Thread(uncheck( () -> { System.out.println("Zzz"); Thread.sleep(1000); })).start(); // Look, no catch (InterruptedException)!
> ```
>
> Hint: Define an
>   interface `RunnableEx` whose `run` method may throw any exceptions. Then
>   implement `public static Runnable uncheck(RunnableEx runner)`. Use a
>   lambda expression inside the `uncheck` function. Why can’t you just use
>   `Callable<Void>` instead of `RunnableEx`?

This is my solution:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RunnableEx extends Runnable {
    @Override
    default void run () {
        try {
            doRun();
        } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("IOBE");
        }
    }

    void doRun ()
        throws Throwable;
}
```

and

```
public class Question6 {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        uncheck(() -> {
            System.out.println("Question6");
        });
    }

    public static Runnable uncheck (final RunnableEx runner) {
        final RunnableEx runnable = () -> {
            try {
                runner.doRun();
            } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
                throw e;
            } catch (Throwable ignored) {
                runner.doRun();
            }
        };

        return runnable;
    }

    // We can not use Callable<Void> because it throws Checked Exception.
}
```

I request two things:

1. How can this be improved, if it can be?
2. As per my understanding, this implementation seems to be correct, but is it really?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
default void run () {
```

There should be no blank after a method name (neither in a declaration not in a call). There are only blanks after `if` and `while` to distinguish them visually from method calls.

---

```
    try {
        doRun();
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("IOBE");
    }
```

Really `IndexOutOfBoundsException`??? What index, what bounds? It should be

```
    try {
        doRun();
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

It's called exception wrapping. You can't throw `e`, so you wrap it into a `RuntimeException` and it can be obtained via `getCause`. Printing the stack does it, so you lose no information.

---

```
    final RunnableEx runnable = () -> {
        try {
            runner.doRun();
        } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
            runner.doRun();
        }
    };
```

The line `runner.doRun()` makes no sense to me. It failed, so you do it again. Why?

Moreover, it may throw a `Throwable`.

Moreover, you're repeating what you did above.

You've been already given a workable example in the question:

```
new Thread(uncheck( () -> { System.out.println("Zzz"); Thread.sleep(1000); })).start(); // Look, no catch (InterruptedException)!
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. As far as IndexOutOfBoundException is concerned, I just wanted to throw any Unchecked exception but yes your point is very valid.